# Make a Button resource and use it in multiple places

Tags: c#, wpf, button, resources

how can i define a global **button** and use it in **multiple** places in **WPF**.

here is my button witch i want to use it in multiple places.

```
<Button x:Key="Attach" Width="90" Margin="220,0,0,0" Content="Attach" Height="16" FontSize="11"/>
```

however i tried to define it in `App.xaml`(`Application.Resources`)

and also in `MainWindow.xaml` (inside `Window.Resources`)

But i cannot access it in **CodeBehind**

```
 Button button = Resources["Attach"];
```

My question is where to define my `button` and if i defined it correct how to use it in **CodeBehind** and **XAML**.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve on a higher level. Is your goal to re-use the button layout/styling? Do you want to provide the same button action in various places?

Comment: yes. i want to have the same button in `StackPanel` witch will be the `Header` of `TreeViewItem`. so yes i have multiple items and i want this button for all of them.@Filburt

Comment: if i know how to use the button i can do the rest! @Filburt

Comment: If you want to use it in a TreeView(item), your button definition will go into the `DataTemplate` you can provide for your TreeViewItem. Currently I only have a Silverlight example at hand, but the concept should work for WPF just the same.

Comment: if i add `DataTemplate` into TreeView it will be added in a treeview as a item. i did not understand what did you mean.@Filburt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
        x:Key="TreeViewMainTemplate" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SubTopics}">
        <Button 
            Width="90" 
            Margin="220,0,0,0" 
            Content="Attach" 
            Height="16" 
            FontSize="11" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Defining a `HiercharchicalDataTemplate` with your button layout will allow you to re-use it as an `ItemTemplate` in  your TreeView:

```
<TreeView 
    Name="TopicTreeView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Topics}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewMainTemplate}">
</TreeView>
```

As you see I'm making intensive use of binding for resources as well as data because I'm building my wpf/sl apps the MVVM way. Doing so makes the need to access controls from code behind obsolete and might be worth looking into for you.

Answer (score 6):

In your **App.xaml** you will have to add and define a style that you want for your buttons.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Attach" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="90" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Attach" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="220,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
        </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And to access it in your **code-behind** you will need to initialize a new style object and populate it with the style you created in your App.xaml. Lastly just add that new style to the style property of your button.

```
Style style = this.FindResource("Attach") as Style;
Button.Style = style;
```